# Displaying a shortened version of an article with HTML content

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, preview

I'm building a website using rails 3.1, which at it's core consists of a bunch of articles (similar to blog posts). These are stored and formatted as HTML. Now, what I need is to generate a preview of the article content so that only a short version is displayed in a feed of these articles. The content will have to be shortened without breaking its HTML.

Is there a simple way of doing this? A gem would be perfect, but ideas for a clean way to implement a shortening function myself would be great too. Thanks!

**Edit:**
On doing further experimentation, I'm currently working with something of this sort, using the [Sanitize gem](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize), and it seems to work out pretty well:

```
def shortened_content(length)
    Sanitize.clean(content[0..length], Sanitize::Config::RELAXED)
end
```

I dislike diluting and changing the direction of my question, but I guess I must.

Is there a better solution for things of this sort? (the sanitize gem, I assume, strips out unwanted content as well as cleans up HTML. I only really need it to clean up the HTML here)

Am I right in thinking I should probably move this processing to the upstream side of things? That is, store the shortened content as well as the full content. I figure it'll save me enough processing time to make it worth the extra storage.

Comment: I'd use [HTML::Trim](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Trim) for this, but I'm not a Ruby user. Still, its source code might prove helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Sanitize gem is the right way to go. I did something similar using the Nokogiri gem - which you can see that the Sanitize gem relies on. It's definitely saner to store the shortened preview of the HTML in a new column in addition to the full HTML. So something like this in a before_save

```
def generate_preview
   self.preview_content ||= shortened_content(100)
end
```

A nice side-effect is that an admin can now manually write a preview if needed.

Comment: Yes, I've implemented something like that :) That bit of code won't handle content edits well though (the shortened version won't update with the main content)

Answer (score 1):

You need something to truncate the html without breaking the tags, try this [jquery truncator plugin](http://henrik.nyh.se/2008/02/jquery-html-truncate)

Comment: Thanks, although I'm looking for something purely server side, I found some nice info through that. Including the rails truncate function, which does some pretty nice stuff although it doesn't clean HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'HtmlSlicer' gem for Rails.

Put this line in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'html_slicer'
```

Then bundle:

```
% bundle
```

Your model:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  slice :content, :as => :shorten, :slice => {:maximum => 100, :limit => 1, :text_break => "..."}
end
```

Your view:

```
<%= @your_model.shorten %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place all the text in a `div` (or any block level element you'd like to use), set it to a fixed size and then put `overflow: hidden;` on it. You could also use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` and the browser will display `...` where it truncates the text - if it supports it.

```
#synopsis {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;   
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

You could possibly end up with a lot of superfluous text which would only serve to increase the size of your HTML which needs to be downloaded.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/KJkaX/)

Comment: Yes, the idea is to shorten the actual content - not just display less of it :) Besides, I doubt that'd be the most accessible of solutions.

Comment: Also, is that feature implemented yet? I tried this on both chromium and firefox on linux and no cigar - no ellipsis is displayed.